# Control Content-Type header for exception mapper

Tags: jersey

In our project we use Jersey 2.29.1.

Now, for our business logic we need to specify different media type for successful responses and for exceptions.

For example we need to implement methods what .expectXML().orJSONError(). Of course in case of custom mapped exceptions we can define custom Content-Type header, but if we have some exception because we don't have a custom mapper, eg NPE, or 404, we have response with default media type.

The idea is send custom header eg X-AcceptErrors to define preferred media type for error response.

How we can redefine default exception mapper with change of media type header for error case?

Thank you!